# Django runserver failing during admin site checks

Tags: django

When running `runserver` command, we are getting the error below which makes breaks the runserver command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                         
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner                                              
    self.run()                                                                                                             
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run                                                           
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)                                                                              
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper                            
    fn(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run       
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)                                                                                    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check                         
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,                                                                   
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks                   
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)                                                                                     
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks                     
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)                                                                            
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 55, in check_admin_app                
    for site in all_sites:                                                                                                 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/_weakrefset.py", line 60, in __iter__                                                     
    for itemref in self.data:                                                                                              
RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
```

This issue started to happen out of nowhere, since all the code related to `AdminSite`'s wasn't modified in months. It's also not happening every time, but increasing in frequency of occurrence.

It doesn't seem to be related to the current implementation, since it's a django's `runserver` issue during the system checks, but here are the Implementation details:

```
class PaymentsAdminSite(AdminSite):
    site_header = "Payments Admin Site"


site = PaymentsAdminSite(name="payments-admin")


@admin.register(models.Payment, site=site)
class PaymentsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def cancel(self, request, queryset):
       pass

    actions = (cancel,)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return models.Payment.objects.all()
```

```
# urls.py
url(r"^payments-admin/", site.urls)
```

Comment: Are you instantiating your own `AdminSite` anywhere. If so, how and where? Can you add this to your question if so.

Comment: added more details

Answer (score 1):

#### Why is the error occurring:

When django runs it loads all of the apps and runs various checks. The default admin interface has various checks. The one that is failing is `django.contrib.admin.checks.check_admin_app`. It loops through `all_sites` and performs a check on each of these sites (`AdminSite`s). The reason this error is being raised is that this set `all_sites` is being edited whilst it is being looped through (obviously a big no no).

How is it being edited? Well... `all_sites` refers to a `WeakSet` in `admin.sites`, and every time you instantiate an `AdminSite`, it adds itself to this `WeakSet`:

```
# django.contrib.admin.sites

all_sites = WeakSet()

class AdminSite:
    def __init__(self, name='admin'):
        ...
        all_sites.add(self)
```

#### Why is this happening?

I'm not 100% sure what is causing the inconsistency but I suspect the module is being loaded in a thread separate to the thread running the checks, and depending on which thread runs faster, the error occurs sometimes and not others.

#### How can I fix it?

Again, without a better idea of what is going on re. threads and what modules are getting imported when, I can't be 100% that this will fix the above, but I'll explain why I think it should work below. Put the following in your `apps.py` of the relevant app:

```
class PaymentsAdminSite(AdminSite):
    site_header = "Payments Admin Site"


site = PaymentsAdminSite(name="payments-admin")
```

#### Why should it fix it

One of the first things Django does first is to register all of the apps in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. This involves importing all of the `apps.py` modules. After it has registered all of the apps, it will then register all of the models, and then it will call the `ready` method in each of the `AppConfig`s. It is the `ready` method in `django.contrib.admin` that is adding the check above, so hopefully by instantiating your `SiteAdmin` in an `app.py` file, it should be instantiated before the check is even added, let alone run.

Note you should only add the `AdminSite` to your `apps.py`, all of the registering of models to it, should stay in your `admin.py` since those models won't even be registered (to django) yet, at the point that `apps.py` is run.